# C# Active Directory - Migrate to System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to migrate some code to the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement classes introduced in .NET 3.5

My old code worked like this and continues to work:

```
var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://{ip address}", "{domain}\\{users}", "{password}", AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
```

My new code running on same machine under the same project doesn't work:

```
var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "{domain}", "ldap://{ip address}/DC=company,DC=local", ContextOptions.Negotiate, "{users}", "{password}");
```

The new code throws an error "The server cannot be contacted", and I feel like it should connect since it's running the same machine and under the same Visual Studio project.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The correct input for the fourth parameter in this case is just `DC=company,DC=local`.

Comment: Thanks I tried this too but still get the same error.  I should note that I'm connecting through a VPN but I'm not sure why that would matter since using the older DirectoryEntry method still works when using VPN.

Comment: It may be a name resolution issue over VPN. Your first example uses an IP (incidentally not a great idea), the latter is going to call Windows APIs to find a DC. You might want to grab a network trace when you repro the problem.